# Select some columns from PCollection (Apache Beam, Python)

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have the following PCollection:
[image]

And I want to select only 2 columns from that PCollection. I tried to do:

```
def cut_data(data):
    return data[["WebSpeedRef", "WebSpeedAct"]]

data_min = data_json | 'min' >> beam.Map(cut_data)
```

but got an error. What is the simplest way to accomplish this.

Comment: What type is the pcollection? Pandas DF? What error do you get?

Comment: Can you provide the error that you have ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
disired_columns = (
    dataset
    | beam.Map(lambda x: [x["column1"], x["column2"]])
)
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.